# Replace database value when recalling in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to change the value of database entries when I recall them in Django.

So I have a database with lots of ON and OFF values as 'value' and time as 'time'.

When I recall these items to display and graph them I want to be able to change all of the 'ON' to 1 and the 'OFF' to 0.

I'm doing a basic recall like this

```
items = Item1.objects.all()
```

Then I want to loop over them and make the changes. Something like.

```
for a in items:
   if items.value == 'ON':
     items.value[a] = 1
   elif items.value == 'OFF':
     items.value[a] = 0
```

Forgive me, I'm still not sure what form items takes on once you use the .object function on it. Is it a dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to transform values on the fly (On => 1, Off => 0).

As you want to transform the values for display purposes only, you have several options to deal with that (none will change the data in DB):

1a. transform values in the custom SQL query using Custom Manager in models.py
     - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods

1b. transform values in the custom raw SQL in your views 
     - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#adding-annotations

2. add derived attribute in your model class using Model Method in models.py

   - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-methods
3. transform values in the view.py code generating the proper values for context in templates
4. transform values in the template code

Where you do that depends on whether and where you want to use the original on/off values and where you want to put the transformation workload.

If you do not need the original values to be processed in Django, then change them on the database level (in the read query), so Django already receives the 0/1 values.

However you might find it easiest to follow option 2 (in models.py).

```
class Item1(models.Model):
    ... your current definitions

    def _bin_value(self):
        "Returns the tranformed ON/OFF value to 0/1."
        if self.value == "ON":
             return 1 
        if self.value == "OFF":
             return 0 
        return None # you should define how you handle empty, NULL or unexpected value
    bin_value = property(_bin_value)
```

And use bin_value in your views instead of value.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds like a good option. So could I amend the model.py file to interpret the values as ON and OFF at source?

Comment: It depends. Like Radek said, if it's not important for you to use the ON / OFF values in your code, then you could do it in the models.py file. However, if it is important in the code, then you could try my suggestion, and test to see what value it has in the template, and then assign it a display value based on that.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect more options and give the example code. Dorian's template example fits to option 4.

Comment: Hi All, thanks Radek, Option 2 is what I'm looking for. Basically this should give me access to both the "ON" and "OFF" values as well as the 1 and 0 values. This is my code. 
        `def _convert_value(self):
            "Returns 1 or 0 instead of ON and OFF"
            if self.value == "ON":
                return 1
            elif self.value == "OFF":
                return 0
            else:
                return 0    
    converted_value = property(_convert_value)`

However I get this error APIInputError: Field 'converted_value' does not exist. Valid lookups are value, time.

Comment: Update. It is working but the problem is with Chartit and trying to get it to read the new 'converted value' item. More to follow.

Answer (score 0):

`Item1.objects.all()` returns a queryset (very similiar to a list) containing all the Item objects. The actual `Item1` class just takes the place of a table in a database. Doing `Item1.objects.all()[0]` will give you the first item object in the queryset. You can also use the `.order_by` method on a queryset to order it by a specific value, such as date or a vote value. Also, after you operate on a database object, you need to save it. So say you have this code:

```
items = Item1.objects.all()
```

Then you'd do

```
for item in items:
    if item.value == 'OFF':
        item.other_value == 1
    item.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Will this actually change the value in the database as all I'm looking to do is change it for display purposes. I don't need to change the actual database value.

Comment: You could do in the template `{% if item.value %} <p>item is value</p> {% endif %}`

Comment: Hi Dorian, thanks for the ideas. I'm using Chartit to chart the values and so am not processing the information in the template and only in the View and then passing it as a completed chart to the template.